# How can I keep the pre-selected options in chosen.js select field

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a multiple select box which I have decided to use chosen.js for, as there are thousands of possible options so it makes things easier for the user.

So far, the select options are prepopulated from the database and on page load the form displays current selected options, also from the database.

My code for the select box is here:

```
$('#skills_chosen').on('click change', function(){
    var items="";
    var typedOpt = $('#skills_chosen').val();
    $.getJSON("php/skillList.php", {term:typedOpt}, function(skillList){
    $.each(skillList,function(index,item) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.skill+"'>"+item.skill+"</option>";
    });
    $("#skills").append(items); 
    $('.chzn-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });

    });  
});
```

This works perfectly fine, as does the prepopulating of the select field using the following code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var myId = "3";     
   $.getJSON("php/getCanSkills.php",{canID:myId}, function(data) {
           for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
               var skillId = data[i].skill_id;
               var skillName = data[i].skill;
               console.log("Skill id: "+skillId+", Skill: "+skillName);
               $('.chosen-choices').prepend('<li class="search-choice">'+skillName+'<a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="'+skillId+'"></a></li>'); 
               $('.chosen-choices').trigger("liszt:updated");
           }
   });
});
```

My problem is, when a user wants to add to the select options and begins typing, the original, dynamically loaded options disappear, which means they would need to enter all of them again as well as adding a new skill. How can I adapt my code to retain the options which are loaded into the .chosen-choices field so the user can simply add another skill to the option group?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. After my for loop I placed the following code:

```
            var preselected =  $('.chosen-choices').html();
            window.preselected = preselected.replace('<li class="search-field"><input value="Start typing..." class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 113px;" type="text"></li>', '');
            console.log(window.preselected);
```

Then at the end of the select box code (following the $('.chzn-select').trigger("chosen:updated"); line) I placed the following line:

```
$('.chosen-choices').prepend(window.preselected);
```

It now works perfectly.

Comment: Actually, I just tested this - works in Firefox but not in Chrome and I also found out that it isn't supported on mobile platforms...I'm going to use select2 instead!